# How yo make a simple calculator in C which saves intermediate result

Tags: c, coding-style

Нi everybody!
I'm solving a problem from the exercise section of S.Kochan's "Programming in C" book and actually got stuck at the problem, which suggests creating a simple calculator in C,which saves intermediate results in the so called "accumulator". So when you enter a value, and then pressing 'S' - the value is supposed to be saved and all further action should be executed with this value. When you press "E'- the prigramm should be over, when you press any of the basic arithmetic sign appropriate action should be don etc. 
I'm using eternal for loop and switch-case operator, but something's wrong. The value is not displayed correctly< so as the arithmetic operations.

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float accumulator, value;
    char operator;

    printf("Calculator\nType in your value:\n");
for(;;)
{
    scanf("%f %c %f", &accumulator, &operator, &value);

    switch(operator)
    {
        case 'S':
        printf("=%.2f\n", accumulator);
        break;
        case 'E':
        printf("=%.2f\nEnd of programm");
        break;
        case '+':
        accumulator=accumulator+value;
        printf("=%.2f", accumulator);
        break;
        case '-':
        accumulator=accumulator-value;
        printf("=%.2f", accumulator);
        break;
        case '*':
        accumulator=accumulator*value;
        printf("=%.2f", accumulator);
        break;
        case '/':
            if(value==0)
                printf("You can not divide by zero");
            else
                accumulator=accumulator/value;
                printf("=%.2f", accumulator);

        break;
        default:
        printf("Unknown symbol");
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
P.S. Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0):

when you press  E ,to exit from the program use exit(0); instead of break

```
 case 'E':
        printf("End of programm");
        exit(0);
```

And in your program you are using accumulator to store intermediate results , but you also taking this as input value in each iteration because of this you may lost the value of accumulator which holds the result of previous operation ,it would be better if you scan accumulator value before loop only once and then use the value of accumulator after each operation

for this you need to modify like this

```
scanf("%f", &accumulator );
for(;;)
{
    scanf(" %c %f",&operator, &value);
...........
```